# How to save tensorboard projector checkpoint file on one machine and open on another machine?

Tags: python, tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard

I visualize my embeddings by [Tensorboard Projector](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/embedding_viz). Saving checkpoint file and visualizing on one machine is no problem. But when I copy the checkpoint file to another machine, tensorboard does not recognize it. Graph still works, but projector does not.

Is Tensorboard Projector checkpoint file portable? How to open it on other machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to save checkpoint with relative path. But it is not enough, the relative metadata path in Projector config file is still not recognizable, so I have to use an adhoc relative path.

In general, you need to go look into each path and fix it, depending on your checkpoint dir structure.